# What is 3^5 here Referring to

Tags: probability

I need some help : *http://di.ubi.pt/~jpaulo/competence/tutorials/hmm-tutorial-1.pdf*

[image]

My question is around this:

```
Suppose that n=5 we must collect statistics for 

3^5 = 243 past histories.
```

This confuses me

If he says  tomorrow prediction based on past 3 days :

would be

*`P(W4=..| W3= , W2= , W1 = )`*

but *`n=5, is 243?`* I thought it would be just

```
P (W5=..| W4 ..to W1)
```

Comment: $SSSSS,SSSSR,SSSSF,SSSRS,SSSRR,SSSRF,\cdots$ and the $237$ following.

Comment: You've got $3$ combinations per day. Going $5$ days back, you have $3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3=3^5$ possible combinations.

Comment: My God, I *was* so confused thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n=5$ you are trying to predict the weather on day $6$ from the the weather on the previous $5$ days.  As there are three possibilities for each day, there are $3^5$ possible sequences of five days of weather.